# map the results from find

Tags: find, pipe, xargs

I have these results from find:

```
$ find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1

subprojects/install-globally-first
subprojects/installation-test-project-custom-config
subprojects/install-via-github
subprojects/init-from-nothing
subprojects/node-path-test
subprojects/install-globally-with-nvm
subprojects/installation-test-project
subprojects/parallel-installs-of-suman
```

I want to map these results to:

```
subprojects/install-globally-first/test.sh
subprojects/installation-test-project-custom-config/test.sh
subprojects/install-via-github/test.sh
subprojects/init-from-nothing/test.sh
subprojects/node-path-test/test.sh
subprojects/install-globally-with-nvm/test.sh
subprojects/installation-test-project/test.sh
subprojects/parallel-installs-of-suman/test.sh
```

(All I am doing in this case is appending "/test.sh" to the results...
I am sure a good solution is something like:

```
$ find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | something (?)
```

but I don't know what it would be! Pretty newby here. Probably more than one way to do it, looking for simplest most robust solution I guess.

Note that since the test.sh files already exist in these paths, I could just to do this:

```
find subprojects -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "test.sh"
```

But I guess I am looking for away to do that, assuming these test.sh files don't exist yet on the filesystem.

Comment: Since you don't appear to want to search subdirectories, you don't really need `find` (at least, not unless you are doing something more complicated than printing the strings). For example, you could just do `printf '%s/test.sh\n' subprojects/*`

Comment: _"Probably more than one way to do it, looking for simplest most robust solution I guess."_ What is your goal here ? What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: @don_crissti my use case is simple here, just trying to get the path to a particular file, but pretending that file doesn't exist yet on the filesystem.

Comment: @don_crissti, the two answers already present are on the right track if that helps, I am open to any solution that works, this is mostly educational

Comment: Since you're using `gnu find` you don't need any post-processing with `sed`, `echo` and whatnot; you can simply do `find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%p/test.sh\n'` (or, if you want them separated by a single space replace the `\n` with a space). Other than that I don't know what to say because I really don't understand the purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to "edit" each line by appending your required suffix:

```
find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | sed 's!$!/test.sh!'
```

The normal separator for `sed` is `/` but I've used `!` because the substitution already contains `/` and I didn't want to end up with `\/` visual constructs in the result (`sed 's/$/\/test.sh/'`).

If you're looking for files that might exist, or don't yet but will, you probably should constrain your `find` to pick out only directories, with `find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

---

In the comments you also then ask how to put this into a single line. Provided none of your arguments contains whitespace (`subprojects/some where/test.sh`, for example) you can pipe the result into `xargs`.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work...also an aside - how can take the find results and change them from newline separated to just single space separated?

Answer (score 1):

To add soemthing in the end a simple echo could also work:

```
find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {}/test.sh \;
#OR to have them in variables
IFS=$'\n';ff=($(find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {}/test.sh \;));echo ${ff[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using GNU Parallel:

```
find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | parallel echo {}/test.sh
```

This will also make it easy to execute them:

```
find subprojects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | parallel {}/test.sh
```